# Which database for scientific data (images of variable size + metadata searching)

Tags: python, database, scientific-computing, data-management

I'm looking for a good database solution to store large (~100's of GB to several TB) amounts of scientific data. Ideally it would be able to handle larger quantities of data.

### Requirements

My datafiles are "images", a ~4 million entry array (1000x1000x3 ints + 1000x1000 floats), plus associated metadata of ~50-100 entries per image. The metadata is stored hierarchically. Images will be organized into one or several "folders" (or "projects"), which themselves can contain other folders. Everything has owners, etc.

I will need to search 100-10,000 images, in one or several folders, based predominantly on its metadata. Then, I might need to pull slices from the image -- I really don't want to load all of the data if I only need a fraction of it. The images should be stored in a compressed format.

**Edit**: It is important to emphasize that I lack uniform data. Images, for instance, are floats or ints of unknown dimensions with typically 10^5-10^6 entries, and the number of metadata per image might vary. Searching metadata across images would of course be limited to those with identical keys.

### Current Approach

My current, and not so great, solution is to mix databases. First, I'm using a SQL database (Django + MySQL right now) to handle "folder", owners, and has a record for each image, but none of its data. I might create records for the metadata as well. Second, I'm using PyTables to store the images and metadata in an hdf5 format and treat it like a database. This solves the slicing and compression problem, and allows me to store the metadata hierarchically, but PyTables does not seem scalable and is far less developed than commercial databases. (It's not made for a multiuser environment: I'm writing my own locks!, which is a bad sign.)

### Help!

I'm not a hardcore programmer, so a standard database solution is strongly preferred. My "optimization" would definitely include maintenance and programming cost. Can anyone recommend favorite database solutions or architectures? Ideas on relational vs hierarchical vs other?

Options might be SciDB (not common, could be good), SQL (heard it's bad for these applications, maybe PostgreSQL?), and HBase (actually, I know nothing about it). I feel like there must be good solutions in the scientific, especially astronomy, community, but the large-scale projects seem to require a serious team to build and maintain.

I'm happy to provide lots more info.

Comment: could you please explain, what is "based predominantly on its metadata" - is it something like EXIF, stored in image header, or some features of images content, or something else? How metadata is connected to image? Why you have a smaller number of metadata items, than number of images?

Comment: I think your basic approach is sound, storing the metadata in a SQL database seems like the logical choice, as it enables you to easily search for your data. Storing the blobs in an SQL database is a really bad idea, don't go that way. You could use something like Cassandra to store the blobs (and perhaps the metadata as well.) Problem with Cassandra is that (in my experience) it's really easy to setup, maintain and use, but it's quite hard to do it correctly.

Comment: Consider also Rasdaman (http://www.rasdaman.com/) and Monet DB (http://www.monetdb.org/Home) both of which have some traction in this area and both of which are, probably, more mature than SciDB is yet.

Comment: dbf: The images are from my research where image ultracold atoms. The metadata is a mix of details about taking the image (viewing rectangle, parameters of the imaging such as the pulse time) and simple properties of our atoms (number, tempertaure, etc.). So, it's well out of the framework of EXIF. I meant that there is 50-100 entries of metadata per image.

HP Mark: How are rasdaman and Monet DB on large arrays, slicing, compression, etc.? A quick look suggests that they both are very interested in scientific data.

Thanks for the quick responses! Keep 'em coming?

Comment: I have no personal experience of either Rasdaman or Monet DB, but contacts in the academic big-data-for-science community tell me that they are both worth considering.  Your use case seems to be right in the spot that both are aiming at, why don't you contact their creators and ask them your questions ?  They're quite approachable. You might also consider moving your question to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you store the data in HDF5 format? Since you already mentioned that you were reluctant to load all of the data, you may not really like the array database options like SciDB, MonetDB or RasDaMan. It is very painful to load big data in raw scientific format into a database, and it usually also requires some extra programming work.

You can check this paper:[Supporting a Light-Weight Data Management Layer over HDF5](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6546110&tag=1). This work proposes to manipulate SQL directly over HDF5.

Comment: Yes, I ended up writing an SQL wrapper around HDF5. The paper looks like a great solution to this problem, and certainly much more advanced than what I've done.